# Convert String long date to datetime in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, str-to-date

I get this value `'Mon Oct 26 16:34:23 CST 2015'` from a table as a String.

I want to convert this string to the next `datetime` value `'2015-10-26 16:34:23'` using `str_to_date()`, as a follow:

```
select str_to_date('Mon Oct 26 16:34:23 CST 2015','%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Y') val;
```

But it returns me a `null` value, if I remove `'%Y'`, I get the next: `'0000-10-26 16:34:23'`.

How I can skip `'CST'` from the String to get the year value?

Use `replace` is the immediate solution, but I can not discard other time zone formats.

In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the timezone itself in the format string.  So, this works:

```
select str_to_date('Mon Oct 26 16:34:23 CST 2015','%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y') val;
```

Of course, this does not work if your strings have other timezones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Given in mind the other time zones, I must use substring (always when the structure never change) to avoid possible problems.

Comment: At the end, I built the query as next:
`select str_to_date(concat(substring('Mon Oct 26 16:34:23 CST 2015',1,20),substring('Mon Oct 26 16:34:23 CST 2015',length('Mon Oct 26 16:34:23 CST 2015')-3,4)),'%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Y') val;`
The only thing must be changed is `'Mon Oct 26 16:34:23 CST 2015'` by the field name. Thanks again!